# Is it possible to turn a widget [Kivy]

Tags: python, widget, kivy

Does kivy have a function which could turn a widget.

For example I have a widget that draws a rectangle. Now the problem is it possible to turn that rectangle by 45 degree?

If it does not have, what would be the best aproach to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible to rotate . You need to change the angle in the Rotate . See below sample code :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


gui = '''
<MyWidget>:
    canvas:
        Rotate:
            axis: 0,0,1
            angle: 45
            origin: self.center
        Color:
            rgba: 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.center
            size: (32, 32)
'''

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    Builder.load_string(gui)

class MyJB(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = MyWidget()
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyJB().run()
```

Comment: This will have the (probably undesirable) side effect of rotating *everything* after that graphics instruction. You should also add PushMatrix and PopMatrix instructions to get the right effect.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to fix the problem.
`canvas.after:  
    PushMatrix:  
    Rotate:  
        axis: 0,0,1  
        angle: self.rotation  
        origin: self.center  
    Ellipse:  
        pos: self.pos  
        size: 20, 15  
    PopMatrix:`